# Single SQL query for retrieval of data with different where clause possible?

Tags: sql, db2

I have to generate a single sql query, which retrieves two columns from two tables.
In where clause the id is `1,2,3,4 and 5`.
How to form a single query with the above specified condition.
I need only sql query but not cursor or functions concept.
Eg;

```
select column 1, column2 from table1, table2 where id=1  
select column 1, column2 from table1, table2 where id=2  
select column 1, column2 from table1, table2 where id=3  
select column 1, column2 from table1, table2 where id=4
```

How to make these multiple queries into a single query???
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

make use of wher in clause will resolve your issue easily ...

#### The IN Operator

The IN operator allows you to specify multiple values in a WHERE clause.

```
select column 1, column2 from table1, table2 where id in (1,2,3,4,5)
```

Answer (score 2):

If the query is the same in each case, just use "in"

```
select column 1, column2 from table1, table2 where id in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

You can also use OR in other cases:

```
select column 1, column2 from table1, table2 where id = 1 OR name = 'XY'
```